# Download file from internet and substring some of it

Tags: java, download

I am creating a program that downloads a file from the internet.
I substring the link, because I want to get the filename from the link.
This is what I have so far.

```
package main;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/8awaehjdh81fqam/CacheName.zip?dl=1";
        int lastSlashIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/');
        String filename= url.substring(lastSlashIndex + 1, 5);

        try{
            URL website = new URL(url);
            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

    }

}
```

It doesn't download the file and I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -37
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Comment: -37 would definitely be out of range of your string...

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: I read the error yes, but I don't know why it says -37?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Java Docs, `public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` is how the substring method is called. The way you're calling it, it's starting at `lastSlashIndex + 1` and ending at index 5 (going backwards, not gonna work). This is why the exception is saying it's out of range at index -37.

You want something more like `url.substring(lastSlashIndex + 1, lastSlashIndex + 1 + 5);`

Comment: Thank you, I don't get any error right now. but where is this getting placed after the download?

Comment: The file written to by the FileOutputStream should go into your current working directory (or wherever the path of your File object is pointing to).

Comment: Thank you, If I want to chagne the directory I have to do this? FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(directory + filename);

Answer (score 2):

@Hypino already answered to your question but I'll just use regex for this purpose. In my opinion it's easiest and most maintainable solution for this case:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DropboxAddressFileName {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String address = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/8awaehjdh81fqam/CacheName.zip?dl=1";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*/(.*)\\?.*$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(address);
        String match = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(match);
    }

}
```

You will get `CacheName.zip` on the output.

Answer (score 1):

```
String filename= url.substring(lastSlashIndex + 1, 55);
```

Comment: I changed it to :String filename= url.substring(lastSlashIndex + 1, url.length() - 5);

Comment: I didn't get that. :P